# Number of elements in centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra

If G is non abelian and a not in Z(G), why is |Z(G)| < |Z(a)| < |G|?

I'm a bit confused... how do we know what elements are in Z(G) for a general non abelian group?

Comment: I am assuming Z(G) is a subroup of Z(a) and Z(a) is a subgroup of G

Answer (score 1):

(i) $a\in Z(a)$ if by $Z(a)$ you mean the centraliser of $a$.

(ii) if $ab\ne ba$ then $b\notin Z(a)$.

Comment: (i) yes. So by (ii) there is one less element in Z(a) and that's how we know |Z(G)| < |Z(a)|.

Comment: Sorry, I meant |Z(a)| < |G| since ab is not equal to ba because there is one less element in Z(a), namely b.